# During GET request handling with flask, I get the error: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am working on a proxy (correct term?) to forward all traffic from my Flask web server to google.com, then return it. (If I go to 127.0.0.1/search?q=stack%20overflow, it should return the content of google.com/search?q=stack%20overflow).

<strike>The error occurs in flask, not my code.</strike>
Thank you to @LukeWoodward for pointing this out.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import requests
import urllib.parse

app = Flask(__name__)

# Add percent codes (like %20) to URLs
def add_percent_codes(urlsection):
    return urllib.parse.quote(urlsection.encode('utf8'))


def parse_sent_args(args_dict):
    args_str = '?'
    for key in args_dict:
        args_str += str(key) + '=' + str(args_dict[key]) + '&'
    return args_str[:-1]


# Define the handling function for every packet
def forward_packet(packet):
    # Modify or process the packet as needed
    print('Received packet:', packet)

    try:
        # Forward the packet to Google.com
        google_response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/' + packet)
        response_to_return = \
            [google_response.content.decode('utf8', errors='ignore'),
             int(google_response.status_code),
             bytes(google_response.headers.items()).decode('utf8', errors='ignore')]
        print('Forwarded packet to Google.com.')

        # Return the response
        return response_to_return
    

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print('Error forwarding packet:', e)
        return 'HTTPError occurred: {}'.format(e), 500
    

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('Error forwarding packet:', e)
        return 'RequestException occurred: {}'.format(e), 500
    
def handle_get_request(path):
    try:
        # Call the handling function for the packet
        response = forward_packet(path)
        
        return response
    finally: pass
    #except Exception as e:
        #print('Error handling GET request:\n')
        #return str(e), 500
    
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET'])
def handle_get(path):
    # Get the incoming packet from the URL path
    args_dict = dict(request.args)
    end_url_args = parse_sent_args(args_dict)
    full_path = '/' + path + end_url_args
    return handle_get_request(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/eesa/Code/proxyforblocking/attempt2.py", line 63, in handle_get
    return handle_get_request(path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/eesa/Code/proxyforblocking/attempt2.py", line 49, in handle_get_request
    response = forward_packet(path)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/eesa/Code/proxyforblocking/attempt2.py", line 30, in forward_packet
    bytes(google_response.headers.items()).decode('utf8', errors='ignore')]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Small note: I commented out error handling to get the full traceback, and added the "finally" block to avoid other errors.

Comment: "The error occurs in flask, not my code": sorry, that's not true. The error most certainly occurs in your code, as is clear from the last line of the traceback. The error even points out that `bytes(google_response.headers.items())` is the code that is causing the error. Looking at this code, I can see why it would generate that error. What are you expecting this piece of code to do?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Sorry, my bad. I was remembering a previous error I fixed in the same code. Changing now, and adding credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is right here in the traceback:

> File "/home/eesa/Code/proxyforblocking/attempt2.py", line 30, in
> forward_packet
> bytes(google_response.headers.items()).decode('utf8', errors='ignore')]
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

The requests Response object contains a dictionary of HTTP headers at [`Response.headers`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-headers), which would be `google_response.headers` in your code.  Calling [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) on this dictionary returns a dictionary view.  You are trying to pass a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) to the [bytes constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), which is failing.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but if you just want to return the headers provided by the `Response` object, you could convert the dictionary to a  string, or you could use the `json` module to create a JSON string representation of the headers dictionary.

For example:

```py
import json

# ...
response_to_return = [
  google_response.content.decode('utf8', errors='ignore'),
  int(google_response.status_code),
  json.dumps(google_response.headers)  # alternatively, str(google_response.headers)
]
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a warped understanding of how this was encoded from before.